# store html symbol in variable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I need to print stored html symbols in an email. Why isn't this working? It prints the symbol string instead of the symbol. ex: `&#8634;` instead of ↺

here is a example of my code:

```
<% event_symbol = "&#8634;"%>
 <%="#{event_symbol}"%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `raw`:

```
 <% event_symbol = "&#8634;"%>
 <%=raw event_symbol%>
```

Comment: second related question. how would I do this?


`<% @test_color = "#86c622;" %>`

`<td style="color:<%=raw @test_color%> !important;"> test color</td>`